# Interconverting different equations for spherical caps in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, analysis, normed-spaces, convex-geometry

I need help in interconverting between these two definitions of a spherical cap in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

> **Figure 9 (Left)**: For a fixed unit vector $v$ and $\epsilon \in [0,1)$, the set $\theta\in S^{n-1}$ for which $$\langle\theta,v\rangle \ge \epsilon$$ is called the $\epsilon$-spherical cap about $v$. It is denoted by $C(\epsilon,v)$. Here $S^{n-1}$ is the sphere of radius $1$, i.e. $$S^{n-1} = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \|x\| = 1\}$$
> **Figure 9 (Right)**: The cap of radius $r$ about $v$ is given by $$\{\theta \in S^{n-1}: \| \theta - v\|\le r\}$$
> [image]

So how do I express $\epsilon$ in terms of $r$? This will help me switch between the two definitions of the spherical cap. Note that we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**My try:**
I started with the second definition and saw that $$\| \theta - v\|\le r \implies \langle \theta - v,\theta-v\rangle \leq r^2 \implies \|\theta\|^2 - \|v\|^2 - 2\langle\theta,v\rangle \leq r^2$$
Since $\theta,v\in S^{n-1}$ we have $\|\theta\| = \|v\| = 1$ so that $$\| \theta - v\|\le r\implies \langle\theta,v\rangle \geq 1-\frac{r^2}{2} $$

Now, looking at the first definition, we see that $\epsilon =-\frac{r^2}{2}$ but we had assumed $\epsilon\in[0,1)$ so this does not make sense!

Where am I going wrong, what am I missing?

**Addendum:**
It was a silly *blunder*. The right inequality is:
$$\| \theta - v\|\le r \implies \|\theta\|^2 + \|v\|^2 - 2\langle\theta,v\rangle \leq r^2 \implies \langle\theta,v\rangle \geq 1 - \frac{r^2}{2}$$
So we get $$\epsilon = 1 - \frac{r^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$\langle \theta - v,\theta-v\rangle \leq r^2 \implies \|\theta\|^2 - \|v\|^2 - 2\langle\theta,v\rangle \leq r^2$$

It should be

$$\langle \theta - v,\theta-v\rangle \leq r^2 \implies \|\theta\|^2 + \|v\|^2 - 2\langle\theta,v\rangle \leq r^2.$$

Comment: Sorry, my blunder! Why do we get $r\leq \sqrt 2$ though?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine What part are you struggling with? The distance between two orthogonal vectors on the surface of the unit ball is $\sqrt{2}$, the corresponding cap has $\varepsilon=0$. If you're also willing to consider caps that go beyond the hemisphere, then you get $\varepsilon\in[-1,1]$ and $r\in[0,2]$., where $r=0$ and $\varepsilon=1$ correspond to the trivial cases of the cap being just a point and $r=2$ and $\varepsilon=-1$ correspond to the entire ball.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused if we're permitted to consider $\epsilon < 0$ or not, i.e. the entire sphere as a cap. Got it now! :)